# ARM Cortex A7: avoid memory veneers?

Tags: arm, compiler-optimization, 32-bit

On ARMv7, which is Thumb capable, is it right that we can avoid all the veneers by using the `BX` instruction?

Since this instruction takes a 32 bit register, are we good?

If yes, when I see veneers in the generated code, I should specialize the output for my machine, right?

Thanks

Comment: Generally, the linker's going to start veneering branches when the targets are too far away - how big's your code?

Comment: And for the case of ARMv4T interworking veneers (which I'd forgotten were a thing), the best solution is likely either "don't target ARMv4T" or "don't bother with Thumb code", depending on what precisely you need to support. Are we talking C code (in which case you can't exactly choose instructions anyway) or assembly code (in which case you ought to be in a position to just use `blx` where appropriate) here?

Comment: It is essentially a gpu stack so addresses can be far away from each others. The BX instruction solves my problem and eventually, as Andrea suggested, relative jump will be used. Thank Notlikethat :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since `BX` takes a 32-bit register, there's no need for veeners because you can cover the whole addressing space.

Of course you'd need to load a 32-bit value into the register, which usually means constant pooling, so if you are looking to squeeze every cycle out of it and your program is not too large you're better off with relative branches. As @Notlikethat notes, if you don't already have the address in a register there's no point in using `BX` when you can just `LDR PC, ...` (unless you need to support ARMv4T interworking).

Relative, non-conditional, 32-bit Thumb branches have a 24-bit addressing space, so you can reach +/- 16MB (for others see [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/Cihfddaf.html)). If you're doing ELF, be *really* careful with 16-bit relative Thumb branches. A 32-bit branch will generate a 24-bit relocation and the linker will insert a veener if the target can't be addressed with 24 bits. A 16-bit branch generates a 11-bit relocation and [ELF for ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044f/IHI0044F_aaelf.pdf) specifies that the linker is **not** required to generate veeners for those, so you'd risk a link-time out-of-range branch.

Comment: Re the second paragraph, if you don't already have the address in a register, then there's really no point using `bx` when you can just `ldr pc,...` directly (except for the unlikely possibility of having to support ARMv4T interworking).